# What can be done with Norwegian brown cheese Brunost other than a sandwich?

Tags: cheese, culinary-uses

Some years ago I tried Norwegian brown cheese [Brunost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunost). I am aware that technically it is not cheese and it is brown and very sweet due to caramelized milk sugar.

I was wondering - is there any other use of this cheese other than a sandwich with some butter and possibly jam/marmalade?

Comment: Congratulations, you seem to have found a good use case for our disputed culinary-uses tag! Normally we would close such a question if the ingredient is unknown to the asker, but recipes abound in its home cuisine (especially when there are translations freely available). I checked this and it seems that not even the Norwegians have much recipes with Brunost.

Comment: Dunno if I've ever met brunost, but my standard answer to "how do you eat gjetost?" is "with a knife, thank you". (Similar to "what do you like to eat Nutella with?" "A spoon.")

Comment: Based on the wikipedia entry, it might make a good fire starter.  (re: a truckload of it burning for 5 days)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brunost is often used in Norwegian cooking, especially in brown sauces.
E.g. [like this](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=no&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tine.no%2Foppskrifter%2Fsesong-og-tema%2Fpr%25C3%25B8v-brunost-i-maten).

I have personly used brunost for such a recipe, and it does add a very nice flavor to the sauce.

[Here is a link to several recepies using brunost](http://www.tine.no/oppskrifter/sesong-og-tema/pr%C3%B8v-brunost-i-maten), from Tine the biggest maker of brunost in Norway)

Hope this helps,
Best wishes from Norway!

Answer (score 2):

I usually eat it with my (homemade) hamburgers - I use it instead of cheddar cheese. Also, I've seen Swedes eat it on rye crispbread (Knäckebröd).

Never tried it with jam! I am experimenting making homemade brunost with walnuts in it... Maybe next time I will try adding pistachios. Bon apetit! Be creative and share the results :)

Answer (score 0):

I make a pizza with it!

ingredients:

- fig spread
- mozzarella cheese, shredded
- gjetost, shredded
- pancetta (diced, or thin slices)
- scallions (chopped)

directions:

- Spread a thin layer of fig spread on pizza crust
- sprinkle with mozzarella and gjetost (2:1 ratio, or to taste)
- pancetta goes on next
- top with scallions